# Is there a polyfill for window.performance.getEntriesByType in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, polyfills

Looks like `window.performance.getEntries` and `window.performance.getEntriesByType` are not defined in Safari.

Is there a polyfill for those functions? Or did someone created sort of alternative?

What I want to do is to get all resources loaded in the page. (all images, css and js files)

Comment: would love to know _all_ the cross-browser performance APIs!  it's time we start getting an accurate measurement of our website load metrics.

Answer (score 3):

Due to Safari does not provide that information in any JavaScript way, it's impossible to create a Polyfill for that.
Stop looking for it. You are not going to have luck with it :(

PS.: Be careful with this answer. Some functions on `window.performance` can be implemented with polyfills, but not the 2 that I asked for (which are necessary for some performance checks)

Comment: If you were a Safari developer I would be voting you down, but given that you are just giving a useful warning, instead I think it deserves an upvote. Safari is lacking in major web standards now a days..

Answer (score 1):

Safari does implement performance.timing; 
The metrics are in epoch time

```
> performance.timing
< PerformanceTiming = $2
connectEnd: 1588977207613
connectStart: 1588977207613
domComplete: 1588977208988
domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1588977208410
domContentLoadedEventStart: 1588977208390
domInteractive: 1588977208390
domLoading: 1588977207819
domainLookupEnd: 1588977207613
domainLookupStart: 1588977207613
fetchStart: 1588977207613
loadEventEnd: 1588977209012
loadEventStart: 1588977209012
navigationStart: 1588977207613
redirectEnd: 0
redirectStart: 0
requestStart: 1588977207685
responseEnd: 1588977207826
responseStart: 1588977207804
secureConnectionStart: 0
unloadEventEnd: 0
unloadEventStart: 0
PerformanceTiming Prototype
```

Comment: Note that `performance.timing` is an old version of the API and is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timing) - no new features are added to the spec etc.